# angular-cli-webpack, How can I include a step to upload to aws s3 as part of production build

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, angular-cli

I started using the webpack flavor of the Angular CLI. I had it working as part of SystemJs flavor.

Is there way I can hook up my node module(which upload the resources in /dist to s3) into webpack configuration (angular-cli.json).